# How can I find out what items get generated in memory when debugging c#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Just curious, is it possible to find out, what items are generated while the program is running in stack and heap? Is there a tool or meachanism out there to identify memory usage in VS2010 C# (Silverlight)?
Thanks,

Comment: I meant instantiated in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Visual Studio Profiler (or any other profiler).

Tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx

Other memory profilers:

- http://memprofiler.com
- http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/
- http://www.xteprofiler.com/ (supports Silverlight)

SO question: [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Answer (score 1):

Its not built into Visual Studio, but you can use [CLRProfiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released.aspx) to visualize allocations on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Reference types are always allocated on the heap.  I *believe* you can assume that value types are allocated on the stack.  I don't know of any tools that will show your total stack usage, though.

You can use [GC.GetTotalMemory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) to determine your app's heap usage.